# How to erase a realtime index in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I want to use a realtime index as an instantly available delta for today's changes, so it needs to be erased nightly. Is there a nice way to remove all documents from an RT-index? I suppose I could select everything from it and issue a `DELETE` for every found id, but that does not seem to be a wise way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`TRUNCATE RTINDEX rt_user` was added in sphinx 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not yet possible. http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=6898 deals with this question and the only solution the forum mentions is shutting down Sphinx, clearing out binlog and the relevant files of the index and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `TRUNCATE RTINDEX ...` without any luck. The easiest method I found was to change the `path` configuration of the index. eg:

`index myindex
{
    type = rt
    path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/myindex
    ...`

to

`index myindex
{
    type = rt
    path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/myindex-v2
    ...`